# Angular 8 Electron 7 build missing "." in webpack:// in Chrome developer tools sources

Tags: angular, webpack, electron, google-chrome-devtools

I recently upgraded to v8 of Angular and v7 of Electron. Prior to the update the sources tab in chrome had the following path (webpack:// > webpack > .). After updating when I run **ng build --watch** and **npm run electron** the app opens correctly but now I cannot debug as the webpack:// only shows "./lib" and "webpack > bootstrap".  The normal src folder and all my components and their associated .ts files are missing from sources, though the app runs correctly.

[chrome dev tools ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsXCl.png)

I have noticed that when I do ng serve and open the localhost page the webpack:// does show the contents correctly. This makes me think it might be caused by Electron packaging up the already packaged angular app, but I'm not sure.

Angular.json config file for the build

```
"build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist/*appName*",
          "index": "src/index.html",
          "main": "src/main.ts",
          "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
          "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
          "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
           ],
           "styles": [
                "src/app/themes/custom-theme.scss",
                "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
            ]
      },
      "configurations": {
          "production": {
           "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
            ],
            "optimization": true,
            "outputHashing": "all",
            "sourceMap": false,
            "extractCss": true,
            "namedChunks": false,
            "aot": true,
            "extractLicenses": true,
            "vendorChunk": false,
            "buildOptimizer": true
        }
    }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",    
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Without the webpack:// files mapping correctly I'm unable to properly debug the project in the chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone that finds themselves in this situation, I was able to correct the issue by downgrading Electron to version 6.1.2.  Keep in mind that if you downgrade you'll need to deal with the fact that Angular is now bundling with type="module" so you'll likely see errors about that on load.

**TL:DR**

- Downgrade to Electron v6.1.2
- Set tsconfig.json to target es5

```
tsconfig.json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",    
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```